# Suggestion engine in dynamodb - querying records without a relation to a different record

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been studying dynamodb docs for the last 2 weeks and made my database design but I'm stuck with one thing although I think I have a quite good understanding of this db engine so far, I cannot crack down the following problem.

Let's say (for simplicity) I have a Spotify like service with the following records in the table:

User record:

- PK: USR_#
- SK: User
- data: name (doesn't really matter)

Song record:

- PK: SNG_#
- SK: Song
- data: title

Listened record

- PK: USR_#
- SK: SNG_#
- data: date listened

Listened record is a record in a database that indicates that a user have listened to a specific song.

Imagine we have thousands of users and thousands of records in the table.

Now, the requirement (access pattern if you will) is to suggest to users songs that they have never listened to.

I spent hours looking into dynamodb docs, but it seems to me that it's impossible to model.

How can I query songs, that a user never listened to?

I could think of some really inefficient ways to model it by adding a list of users to a Song record which is obviously ridiculous in my opinion because I would have to scan all the Songs and filter by attribute where the USR_# does not exist.

Is there any more efficient pattern to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Keep all the listened SNG# of the logged in user from the Listened record table and keep it in memory(Say HashMap). Write a logic to randomly pick the SNG_# from the Song record which is not in the in memory MAP and suggest that song.

I believe this can be better handled at the app layer than the DB layer. As Dynamodb doesn't have joins, you need to build a join like logic in the app.

Comment: What if I use lambda functions? The memory wouldn't persist. 
Also, I'm using JavaScript. I quickly checked and HashMap is a Java thing.
I could use Redis, but what if I need to purge the memory for some reasons?

Comment: Also, how would you exclude the records (songs) that a user listened to? It would require in the worst case scenario n-1 calls to a database where n is the number of records. Which means that if I have 1M Songs, I would have to query the db 99999 times only for one user. And I could have thousands of them.